# MPMoviePlayerController video does not fill up the entire view

Tags: iphone, ios, mpmovieplayercontroller, ipad

I am trying to add a MPMoviePlayerController view to my app. I am trying to control the position of it in code, and then place my own buttons underneath it (just a fullscreen and play/pause button).

However, the video does not take up the entire area of the video player. Is this normal? Can I make it so the entire thing is video?  (This is what I mean: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NjAxj.png)

This is how I am implementing it:

in .h:

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController
@property (nonatomic, strong) MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayerController;
@end
```

in .m:

```
 NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost:8013/prog_index.m3u8"];
 _moviePlayerController =  [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];
 _moviePlayerController.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone;

// This places the player exactly where I want it. When I want it full screen
// I can dynamically update these values?
[_moviePlayerController.view setFrame:CGRectMake(100, 181, 650, 500)];

 _moviePlayerController.view.layer.borderColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.329 green:0.80  blue:0.227 alpha:1].CGColor;
 _moviePlayerController.view.layer.borderWidth = 2.0;

_moviePlayerController.shouldAutoplay = YES;
[self.view addSubview:_moviePlayerController.view];
[_moviePlayerController play];
```

Everything seems to work fine, except there are those black bars above and below the video. I would like it to be just possible, and replace the bottom one with my custom controls. Any thoughts?

Also, is this the best way to position the player?

Comment: did you tried _moviePlayerController.fullscreen = YES

Comment: I did. You know, I think it's just because the video is only a certain height. If I make the video size shorter that will work. Thanks.